Get the pid of the process running in remote server using golang
I am trying to get the pid of the command that is executed using ssh session in a remote server. But the pid is coming empty. Any help on this?
Here is my program..
    func (c *SSHClient) RunCommandWithContext(ctx context.Context, command string) (string, error) {
    if c.Client == nil {
        return "", errors.New("SSH client is not connected")
    }

    session, err := c.Client.NewSession()
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    defer session.Close()

    var stdoutBuf bytes.Buffer
    session.Stdout = &stdoutBuf

    // Channel to signal completion
    done := make(chan error, 1)

    // Run the command and get the PID
    var stdout, stderr bytes.Buffer
    session.Stdout = &stdout
    session.Stderr = &stderr

    go func() {
        done <- session.Run(command)
    }()

    // Extract the PID from the output
    output := strings.TrimSpace(stdout.String())
    fmt.Println("Output:", output) <-- this is coming empty
    pid, err := strconv.Atoi(output)
    fmt.Println("PID:", pid) <--- I need the pid of the command I am executing remoting.
    fmt.Println("Error:", err)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to parse PID: %v", err)
    }
    log.Printf("Started command with PID %d\n", pid)

    ticker := time.NewTicker(2 * time.Second)
    defer ticker.Stop()
    for {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            // Context timeout
            if err := session.Signal(ssh.SIGKILL); err != nil {
                return "", fmt.Errorf("failed to kill process: %w", err)
            }
            return "", ctx.Err()
        case <-ticker.C:
            log.Println("Checking command status...")
            if !isProcessRunning(session, pid) {
                log.Println("Command finished successfully")
                printLogs(stdout.String(), stderr.String())
                return "", nil
            }
        case err := <-done:
            // Command completed
            if err != nil {
                return "", err
            }
            return stdoutBuf.String(), nil
        }
    }
    return "", nil
}

// This program asynchronously checks if the command has completed or not
func isProcessRunning(session *ssh.Session, pid int) bool { 
    command := fmt.Sprintf("ps -p %d", pid)
    if err := session.Run(command); err != nil {
        return false
    }
    // Run the command and get the PID
    var stdout, stderr bytes.Buffer
    session.Stdout = &stdout
    session.Stderr = &stderr
    output := strings.TrimSpace(stdout.String())
    return strings.Contains(output, strconv.Itoa(pid))
}

I am trying to achieve the below ansible code in golang as we are in the process of migrating the code to golang,
- name: Update  cluster
  shell:
    cmd: "{{ bmctl_tool }} update cluster -c {{ cluster }} --workspace-dir {{ abm_path }} --kubeconfig {{ cluster_kubeconfig }} --bootstrap-cluster-pod-cidr {{ bootstrap_cluster_pod_cidr }} --bootstrap-cluster-service-cidr {{ bootstrap_cluster_service_cidr }}"
  environment:
    GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: "{{ gcp_service_account }}"
  async: 2000
  poll: 0
  register: cluster_update

- name: Check on cluster update async task
  async_status:
    jid: "{{ cluster_update.ansible_job_id }}"
  register: update_job_result
  until: update_job_result.finished
  no_log: true
  retries: 100
  delay: 20


Is the whole point of getting the pid to check whether the command is running? Session can do that for you.

Actually with the help of pid, I need to check if the command has successfully completed or exited with some failure status..Please let me know how this can be achieved using session itself

You can't get exit status from ps -- after something exits, whichever parent process inherited it (or init, PID 1) gets a SIGCHILD, telling that process to use waitpid() to read the exit status; as soon as it's read, it's no longer in the process table and stops showing up in ps (and even before that, something exited but unreaped shows up in ps with a Z, not with exit details). The easy thing to do is to leave your SSH connection open while the remote process is running, and check the exit status returned by ssh.

Use Session.Wait() per https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/crypto/ssh#Session.Wait -- it'll give you the remote exit status itself, with none of this silly polling.

Session.Wait and Session.Run have the same behavior, so no need to Start / Wait, you can just Run and use that error to decide what to do


Actually with the help of pid, I need to check if the command has successfully completed or exited with some failure status..Please let me know how this can be achieved using session itself

I'm not sure how you plan to get from a PID to its exit status.  But no need to do that anyway!  ssh.Session supports this itself.
ssh.Session.Run returns an error if the command does not succeed:

The returned error is nil if the command runs, has no problems copying stdin, stdout, and stderr, and exits with a zero exit status.
If the remote server does not send an exit status, an error of type *ExitMissingError is returned. If the command completes unsuccessfully or is interrupted by a signal, the error is of type *ExitError. Other error types may be returned for I/O problems.

If you get an error from Run(), you can do a type assertion or errors.As  to see if it's an *ssh.ExitError.  If it is, you know the command failed and can handle that as necessary.
If you get an *ssh.ExitError, you can determine the exit code if you wish.  More useful will be to include the stderr buffer in any error message, as it will contain any explanation the command may provide concerning why it failed.
You can then remove the ticker and the ps logic and all that.  You never need to poll to see whether a subprocess has ended, in any language; there's always a way to wait.

Thankyou for your detailed answer. I am not an expert in Golang yet, But I will try to understand what you have mentioned above.
I have also added the ansible script that we are trying to migrate as golang code in my question above. Could you please check that once and let me know if this is still achievable by how you are saying?

It's been a while since I touched ansible, but yeah I think it still makes sense.  Go's handling of parallelism and concurrency is much better than ansible's.  So instead of all that silly async / polling behavior in ansible, you can just spawn off a goroutine for each ssh connection, have each goroutine wait for the command to exit, and report failures back on a chan<- error

Thankyou very much.. I am trying it

If you get stuck, feel free to open a new question.
